# How do you Mock an class for a unit test that has a return type but no input parameters

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a method in code that returns an OrganisationModel.

```
public virtual OrganisationModel GetCurrentUserOrganisation()
{
    var user = DBEntities.AspNetUsers.Find(_userId);
    if (user.ActiveOrganisation != null)
    {

       var org = user.OrganisationUsers.Where(p => p.organisationId == 
    user.ActiveOrganisation).Where(p => p.userId == _userId).FirstOrDefault();
        if(org != null)
        {
            if (org.Organisation != null)
            {
                return org.Organisation.ToModel();
            }
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;    
}
```

I want to write a unit test on a class that uses this method my test looks like this

```
public void Index()
{
    HttpContext.Current = _TestContext;
    var _GovernorLogic = new Mock<GovernorLogic>();

    var testdata = new OrganisationModel { OrganisationId = 3, OrganisationName = "Test Org" };


    var _OrganisationLogic = new Mock<OrganisationLogic>(new UserId { userId = "e58bf834-2c06-4cc0-ac00-231a5e1a9bbc" }) ;
    _OrganisationLogic.Setup((OrganisationLogic p) => p.GetCurrentUserOrganisation()).Returns((OrganisationModel model) => testdata).Callback((OrganisationLogic a) => receivedorganisation = a.GetCurrentUserOrganisation());

    GovernorsController controller = new GovernorsController(_OrganisationLogic.Object);

    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

When I run this I get an error telling me that

> System.ArgumentException Invalid callback. Setup on method with 0 parameter(s) cannot invoke callback with different number of parameters (1). Source=Moq StackTrace: at Moq.MethodCallReturn`2.ValidateNumberOfCallbackParameters(MethodInfo 
>       callbackMethod) at Moq.MethodCallReturn`2.ValidateReturnDelegate(Delegate callback) at Moq.MethodCallReturn`2.Returns[T](Func`2 valueExpression)

How do I test a method that accepts no input parameters but has a return type?

The Controller Action Method I am trying to test is shown below along with the Constructor for the Controller.

```
[Inject]
public GovernorsController(GovernorLogic GovernorLogic, OrganisationLogic logic) : base(logic)
{
     _GovernorLogic = GovernorLogic;
}



public ActionResult Index()
{
    var CurrentGovernors = _GovernorLogic.GetAllCurrentGovernors(Organisation.GetCurrentUserOrganisation().OrganisationId).ToList().Select(p => p.ToViewModel()).ToList();
    var ArchivedGovernors = _GovernorLogic.GetAllArchivedGovernors(Organisation.GetCurrentUserOrganisation().OrganisationId).ToList().Select(p => p.ToViewModel()).ToList();

    var Model = new GovernorsViewModel
    {
        CurrentGovernors = CurrentGovernors,
        ArchivedGovernors = ArchivedGovernors,
    };

    return View(Model);
}
```

The base controller that is inherited by GovernorsController is shown below:

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private OrganisationLogic _organisationLogic;
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        private string _userId;

        [Inject]
        public BaseController(OrganisationLogic OrganisationLogic)
        {
            _userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            _organisationLogic = new OrganisationLogic(new UserId {userId= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()});
        }

        protected OrganisationLogic Organisation
        {
            get
            {
                return _organisationLogic;
            }
        }

        public BaseController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;


        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            set
            {
                _signInManager = value;
            }
        }


        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
           set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

***------ Minimal Complete Example -------***

**Base Controller**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private OrganisationLogic _organisationLogic;
    private string _userId;

    [Inject]
    public BaseController(OrganisationLogic OrganisationLogic)
    {
        _userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        _organisationLogic = new OrganisationLogic(new UserId {userId= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()});
    }

 [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult UserOrganisations()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var ViewModel = _OrganisationLogic.GetAll().ToList().Select(p=>p.ToViewModel());
            return PartialView("_UserOrganisations", ViewModel);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

}

```
///The child action in the base controller is use in the layout page to render organisation in a drop down list. It is this that is making use of _OrganisationLogic /////
@Html.Action("UserOrganisations", "Base",new {area = "" })
```

**GovernorsController**

```
public class GovernorsController : OrganisationBaseController
{

    [Inject]
    public GovernorsController(OrganisationLogic logic) : base(logic)
    {

    }


    // GET: Organisation/Governors
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var Model = new SomeModel();

        return View(Model);
    }

}
```

**OrganisationLogic**

```
public class OrganisationLogic : LogicRepository<OrganisationModel>
{
    private string _userId;
    public OrganisationLogic(UserId userId)
    {
        _userId = userId.userId;
    }

    public override List<OrganisationModel> GetAll()
    {
        var orgs = DBEntities.Organisations.Where(p=>p.IsDeleted!=true).ToList().Select(p=>p.ToModel()).ToList();
        return orgs;
    }
```

}

Comment: Few questions:1) for what do you need `receivedorganisation`? 2) why are you passing `UserId` to `Mock`?

Comment: Are you trying to test the controller or `GetCurrentUserOrganisation`?

Comment: No the test is for the Index Action on GovernorsController. This action uses GetCurrentUserOrganisation() to populate the model. so I need to mock the return from GetCurrentUserOrganisation() so I can test that GovernorsController transforms the returned organisation correctly into the ViewModel

Comment: I don’t necessarily need receivedorganisation. As i’ve Googled around the issue some sites suggested I needed to pass the object returned into a new variable so it’s languishing around following those efforts. It’s not currently being used in the test.

UserId is passed to the constructor of OrganisationLogic making it available to the whole of the class. It is used in the method i’m Testing (this works fine). The reason for passing it in this way is that the class sits in a separate Business Logic later that doesn’t have access to asp.net identity or the HTTP context of the application.

Comment: Show the method under test along with the used dependencies so a proper unit test with mock can be built.

Comment: I've posted the controller method that I am trying to test within the question ^^

Comment: Given your answer to Johnny's question, I'd say you don't need the Callback. Your question was "How do I test a method that accepts no input parameters but has a return type?", and the way to do that is the line which does Setup and Returns; but without the Callback. P.S. I'm not sure why it's written ".Setup((OrganisationLogic p) => p" ( is that the new C#7 inline declaration?); I would have expected ".Setup(p => p", and similar for the 2 other lambdas on the same line.

Comment: Cheers for that - I've tried without a callback and I get the same error. I also thought the need to specify callback was overkill but it was a way I could get some visibility and control over the callback parameters. Removing it doesn't make a difference.

Also adjusted the line so that it doesn't explicitly state OrganisationLogic p - doesn't make a difference, there's nothing wrong with declaring the type, its just not needed as its normally inferred.

The line now reads 
_OrganisationLogic.Setup(p => p.GetCurrentUserOrganisation()).Returns((OrganisationModel model) => testdata);

Comment: Still havn't found a solution to this - when I remove the call back function and the test data the method runs as if it is running the actual method - it errors because it can't find .activeorganisation which comes from the user object. I don't think the test method should ever hit this as it is supposed to simply return the test data - any further help very much appreciated.

Comment: @SteveWestgarth alright, I've been busy this weekend. I'll see if I can take a further look at this. My main issue is with reproducing the issue as I am seeing things that would require me asking a lot of questions to figure out about your current design.

Comment: No worries at all - if it helps I'm happy to do a screen share with you to show the design pattern I've used and answer questions - could maybe take a chat or Skype session? Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: in a [mcve] show `GovernorLogic`, `OrganisationLogic` and explain what is happening in the first two lines of the method under test as it seems to be accessing members from the base class. so that code is hidden and I have no way of understanding what is being accessed from where. I can make assumptions but that wont help much.

Comment: Just some advice. the difficulty in unit testing code is directly related to how well the code is designed. try to keep your code simple (KISS principle)

Comment: Ok, i'm happy to share the base controller but there is a fair amount going on in it - i'll modify the question in a second to see if I can simplify whats going on.

In essence the project has 3 layers, Presentation, Business Logic and DAL. 

_OrganisationLogic and _GovernorLogic are in the Business Logic layer and provide access to data.

In the base controller _OrganisationLogic is setup (taking a parameter of type String UserId) making this available to all controllers. This is the Mock that is failing.

For the purposes of the question _GovernorLogic can be ignored

Comment: as if its not in use by the controller at all - _OrganisationLogic does need to return through as when I further develop the controller I will make use of it

Comment: I would love to be able to test the controller without mocking _OrganisationLogic but because the controller inherits from base I don't think i'm able to do this?

Comment: That is a code smell as your code seems tightly coupled to implementation concerns that are making your code difficult to test in isolation. May not be what you want to hear but your code seems to be in need of refactoring as there a design issues evident by the current situation.

Comment: Just noticed in the base controller that you are not using the injected parameter as you are manually initializing a new instance of `OrganisationLogic`  in the constructor.

Comment: The more code I see the more design issues appear. I suggest you delete this question and review the code. Looking particularly at how tightly the code is coupled to implementation concerns. It is way to broad to address all those problems here as this is now an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Cool - i'll go back to the drawing board and come back to you - I still feel though that even if you take the base controller out of the situation completely i'll still have the same problem with mocking organisation logic. I'll write a an example that shows this an as you suggest raise another question assuming the issue is still there.

Comment: Finally, classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions, to that end inject interfaces or abstraction classes.

Comment: @Nkosi in response to your request last night to create a Minimal Verifiable Example I have posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244545/how-do-you-moq-a-class-for-unit-test. This should give a much clear view as to what my problem is (Please not although the error message appears different I think the issue is caused by the same problem. Any help you can give would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'll take a look when I can.

Comment: Thank you - your help is very much appreciated.